# Secure communication between django server and iphone app

Tags: iphone, django, https, lighttpd, security

I'm writing an iPhone application that needs to send small bits of information (two strings of under 128 characters each, at a time, and this doesn't happen too frequently) to a server when users interact with it. I would like this information to remain confidential, so I'm thinking of some sort of encryption or secure connection would be necessary.

My question is about the server side of things. The server the iPhone app has to communicate with is written in django and is running on lighttpd. What is the most appropriate way (or what is a standard way) of doing this. I was thinking https, which I know on the iPhone I can use ASIHTTPRequest to do a POST request, but I don't know what it requires on the server side. Do I need a certificate? How does the data get encrypted/secured? Are there any django modules to help with this? Do I have to do something to configure lighttpd?

Would something like xml-rpc or json-rpc be simpler? Is it possible to secure such communication? At what level would that occur?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using xml-rpc or json-rpc are only means to encapsulate your data into a form that is easy to transport. Your iPhone app can transform the Objective C data using one of those formats and your Django server app can transform the data back into Python objects.

Neither of these have *anything* to do with security.

Creating an HTTPS (SSL) connection encrypts all communication between the client (iPhone) and the server (Django). You will need to get a certificate for the server side. This indicates to the client that the server is who it claims to be. Your next line of research down this path should be about how to configure lighttpd to handle SSL traffic. Once lighttpd negotiates the SSL communication, your Django app will operate as it does for non-secured traffic.

This is your best choice.

If, for whatever reason, you don't want to use SSL, then you could find strong encryption libraries for both ends of the communication. The iPhone app could encrypt the data, send it over an HTTP connection and the Django app could decrypt it. For example, the [pycrypto](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/) Python library implements strong encryption ciphers such as [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) and [Blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29). You might be able to find an implementation of one of these ciphers written in Objective C.

Did you notice that this is getting increasingly complex?

Go with SSL. It's the way security is done for HTTP-based communication.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm it looks like this might be what you're after, have you seen it?

[Setting up SSL for Lighttpd/Django](http://coderseye.com/2008/setting-up-ssl-for-lighttpddjango.html)

If I read that right, that setup allows your server to answer https and http requests (?)
Then if your whole app isn't going to be https there's this [SSL Middleware](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/85/) to help configure some paths as ssl and some not.

Answer (score 1):

If you use https (SSL) on the server side it shouldn't matter if you use XML-RPC or JSON-RPC. All the data you transfer will be encrypted and secure.

I can only speak from our Rails application and nginx. I bought a SSL certificate from GoDaddy (very cheap) and nginx is setup to encrypt the content (Rails is not doing this itself) on the fly when it sends it out. On the iPhone ASIHTTPRequest will be responsible to decrypt the data. All other layers shouldn't be concerned about the encryption, you can send anything you want.

You might also be able to use a self-signed certificate. We decided to use GoDaddy as we also use the SSL certificate for regular browsers, and those show a warning message to the user if they encounter a self-signed certificate, which obviously scares people away.